# How to write a test case to verify OAuth token?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, integration-testing

We have a GoLang backend service(OAuth enabled) that accepts http requests, with `Authorization` header with value `"Bearer" + OAuthTokenString`.

How to write a unit or integration test case for backend service to verify that backend service is OAuth enabled(verifies the token)? am not sure, we cannot create a mock service(`httptest.NewServer`) with OAuth enabled....

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. I can see that your team is concerned about minimizing possible errors through testing the code. This is an aspect that many developers often forget.

Without having seen your code, it is a bit difficult to suggest a 100% correct answer for your case.

I will assume that my example will serve as a guide to write your own test or in the best case to optimize the example that I suggest

I was using `gin gonic` as the HTTP web framework for my project and I wrote a method Authenticate that is called as middleware for each protected endpoint. Then for testing I only created an http server through the `gin.Default ()` method

```
// Authenticate auth an endpoint
func Authenticate() gin.HandlerFunc {
  return func(c *gin.Context) {
    var someErr errors.BukyError
    someErr.SetUnauthorized()

    // Fetch token from the headers
    requiredToken := c.GetHeader(constants.AuthorizationHeader)
    if len(requiredToken) == 0 {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(someErr.HttpErrorCode, someErr.JSON())
        return
    }

    splittedToken := strings.SplitN(requiredToken, " ", 2)
    if len(splittedToken) != 2 || strings.ToLower(splittedToken[0]) != "bearer" {
        primErr := fmt.Errorf("wrong bearer token format on Authorization Header")
        someErr.PrimitiveErr = &primErr
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(someErr.HttpErrorCode, someErr.JSON())
        return
    }

    // Get email from encoded token
    jwtToken, claims, err := helpers.DecodeJWT(splittedToken[1], false)
    if err != nil {
        someErr.PrimitiveErr = &err
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(someErr.HttpErrorCode, someErr.JSON())
        return
    }

    if _, err := helpers.VerifyObjectIDs(claims.Subject); !err.IsNilError() {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(someErr.HttpErrorCode, someErr.JSON())
        return
    }

    // Set the User variable so that we can easily retrieve from other middlewares
    // c.Set("User", result)
    c.Set(constants.ReqBukyJWTKey, jwtToken)
    c.Set(constants.ReqBukyClaimsKey, claims)

    // Call the next middlware
    c.Next()
  }
}
```

And then I just tested like following

```
func TestAuthenticate(t *testing.T) {
  userID := primitive.NewObjectID().Hex()
  email := "email@email.com"
  firstName := "My Name"
  lastName := "My Lastname"
  scopes := []string{"im_scope"}

  statusOK := "statusOK"
  someProtectedPath := constants.UsersPath + "/" + userID

  engine := gin.Default()
  engine.GET(someProtectedPath, Authenticate(), func(c *gin.Context) {
      c.String(http.StatusOK, statusOK)
  })

  t.Run("NoTokenHeader", func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("UnsetHeader", func(t *testing.T) {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
        engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, w.Code)
    })

    t.Run("EmptyHeader", func(t *testing.T) {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
        req.Header.Set(constants.AuthorizationHeader, "")
        engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, w.Code)
    })
  })

  t.Run("TokenWithBadFormat", func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("1", func(t *testing.T) {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
        badFormatedToken := "hola.hola"
        req.Header.Set(constants.AuthorizationHeader, fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", badFormatedToken))
        engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, w.Code)
    })

    t.Run("2", func(t *testing.T) {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
        badFormatedToken := "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ."
        req.Header.Set(constants.AuthorizationHeader, fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", badFormatedToken))
        engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, w.Code)
    })

    t.Run("3", func(t *testing.T) {
        w := httptest.NewRecorder()
        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
        badFormatedToken := "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.hola.hola.hola"
        req.Header.Set(constants.AuthorizationHeader, fmt.Sprintf("Bearere %s", badFormatedToken))
        engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
        assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, w.Code)
    })
  })

  t.Run("ExpiredToken", func(t *testing.T) {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
    expirationTime := time.Second
    expiredToken, _, err := helpers.GenerateAccessJWT(userID, email, firstName, lastName, scopes, expirationTime)
    time.Sleep(expirationTime * 2)
    req.Header.Set(constants.AuthorizationHeader, fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", expiredToken))
    engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusUnauthorized, w.Code)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
  })

  t.Run("ValidToken", func(t *testing.T) {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", someProtectedPath, nil)
    validToken, _, err := helpers.GenerateAccessJWT(userID, email, firstName, lastName, scopes)
    req.Header.Set(constants.AuthorizationHeader, fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", validToken))
    engine.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusOK, w.Code)

  })
}
```

Comment: Am trying with `httptest.NewServer`